# Set Content for UIScrollview in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a tableview where I want to display uiscroll view in its row. I have set height of the tableview as following:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
    let deviceFrame = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    print((1.21*deviceFrame.width))
    return (1.21*deviceFrame.width)
}
```

Now I have a custom table view cell, Inside that tableview cell I am trying to add pages for uiscrollview as following:

```
func loadContent(){
    var xaxis = 0
    var numOfPages = 0
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    for index in 1...3 {
        let pagevw = CustomPageView(frame: CGRect(x: xaxis, y: 0, width: Int(scrlvw.frame.size.width), height: Int(scrlvw.frame.size.height-10)))
        pagevw.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        scrlvw.addSubview(pagevw)
        xaxis = xaxis + Int(screenSize.width)
        numOfPages += 1
    }
    let content = CGSize(width: numOfPages * (Int(scrlvw.frame.height)), height: Int(scrlvw.frame.height-30))
    print("content")
    print(content)
    scrlvw.contentSize = CGSize(width: numOfPages * (Int(scrlvw.frame.height)), height: Int(scrlvw.frame.height-30))
    pagecontrol.numberOfPages = numOfPages
}
```

Now although cell is coming up correct but content size of table is not updated correctly. Probably autolayout is creating some trouble here. Although I want autolayout to remain as I have many components inside my page.

Comment: Nothing you've posted here shows anything related to the "content size of table" ... You are returning `(1.21*deviceFrame.width)` as the Height for *every* row in your table -- do you mean you create, say, 12 rows like this in your table but your table doesn't scroll up and down?

Comment: I meant content size of the UIScrollView in table row, table is fine but scrollview doesn't get correct content size because of auto layout.

Answer (score 0):

When you dynamically add auto-layout content to a UIScrollView, you want to add the proper constraints to the subviews, rather than using the old style of setting each subview's x,y,w,h and then calculating the scrollview's ContentSize.

When doing so, you use constraints not only to position the "pages" (the embedded subviews), but also to "push out" the sides of the scrollview's content size.

I put together a sample of adding subviews to a horizontally scrolling UIScrollView embedded in a vertically scrolling UIScrollView. It's in Swift 2.2, but it auto-updates to 3.0 without issues.

https://github.com/DonMag/SWAutoLayoutScrollView

I played around with several different ways to assign constraints, all of which accomplished the same thing. The "working" methods are still in the main view controller class.

You *should* be able to replicate those techniques to solve your scrolling needs.